# Excel Macro (save to Sharepoint Library) no longer accepting full stop?

Tags: sharepoint, excel, vba

Code is below which was working fine, now does not seem to like the `".xlsm"` section. problem is on all PCs. I tried using the `Filename=` and a few variants and have pinned it down to `"."` (period) that it does not accept in `".xlsm"`, delete the period and it is fine but then lands in SharePoint as an unknown file (with no file extension). Any advice appreciated!

```vb
Sub SUBMIT()
Dim FName As String

FName = Range("E3").Text
FDate = Range("I3").Text

If Range("E3") = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Your Name"
Range("E3").Select
ElseIf Range("I3") = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Fortnight Ending Date"
Range("I3").Select
ElseIf Range("I3") <> "" Then
If MsgBox("Are you sure? (Have you entered your supervisor(s) and Fortnight End Date in the top panel ?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("https://*****.sharepoint.com/corp/payroll/Timesheets" & FName & " " & FDate & " " & "Timesheet" & "xls")
MsgBox "Timesheet Submitted"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `FileFormat` property of the `.SaveAs()` function of `ActiveWorkbook` ? [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Answer (score 0):

You should supply the file path **without** the extension and use the `FileFormat` parameter of the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs()` function.

In your case, you should change the row to this

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("https://*****.sharepoint.com/corp/payroll/Timesheets" & FName & " " & FDate & " " & "Timesheet"), 52
```

The `52` I added at the end is the value for `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

The code below works well for me on Win7 Excel2013

```vb
Sub StackOverflow()

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Temp\myfile", 52

End Sub
```